# JavaScript: z-index doesn't change after first mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, hover, z-index, mouseover

I'm trying to allow the user to rollover the arrows which makes a div appear below (and remain there even after mouseover). I've had some success but have hit a wall.

It only works from left to right, if I want to hover over an arrow that's to the left and I've already hovered over an arrow that's on the right, it isn't possible.

Here's the code:

```
$(".business-strategy").one("mouseover", function() {

    $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "10");
    $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
});

$(".accelerating-innovation").one("mouseover", function() {

    $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "10");
    $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
});

$(".cloud-and-technical-services").one("mouseover", function() {

    $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "10");
    $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
});

$(".procurement-and-supplier-services").one("mouseover", function() {

    $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "10");
});
```

I'm quite new to JavaScript to please forgive any newby errors!

Any help would be very much appreciated! :-)

Heidi

Comment: Please do not link to your web site. Here is why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Instead of `one` use `on`. This is how `one` works - `Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.`

Comment: @diodeus a better alternative would be a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS**

```
$(".business-strategy").on("mouseenter", function() {

    $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "10");
    $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
 })
.mouseleave(function() {
    $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "10");
    $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
 });
$(".accelerating-innovation").on("mouseenter", function() {

   $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "10");
   $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
}).mouseleave(function() {
   $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "10");
   $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
 });

$(".cloud-and-technical-services").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "10");
    $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "-1");
    $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "10");
    $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
 });

$(".procurement-and-supplier-services").on("mouseenter", function() {
   $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "10");
}).mouseleave(function() {
   $(".business-strategy2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".accelerating-innovation2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".cloud-and-technical-services2").css("z-index", "-1");
   $(".procurement-and-supplier-services2").css("z-index", "10");
 });
```

**Or**

You can combine both `$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.classname', function (ev) {` then write all functions again..

Comment: Something as simple as a spelling mistake! Thank you - I've been scratching my head all day! Heidi.

Comment: Is the mouseleave really necessary?

Comment: You can combine mouseleave with mouseenter like I suggested instead of writting them again. But yes, `mouseleave` is really necessary because that's what happens when mouse is not over any button. - to maintain the current state